# Binding to strings containing custom components in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, custom-component

I'm trying to display a string, pulled from my model, that contains ember custom components. They don't seem to get compiled though -- see (1) and (2) in the output.  If I replace the custom components with standard html elements and use the {{{-}}} syntax for binding, things look right (see (3) and (4) in the output), but this is not sufficient for the application I have in mind, though. How can I get ember to compile the custom components before displaying them?

app.js:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

var g1 = "{{#my-bold}}Yo{{/my-bold}}, {{#my-italic}}dude{{/my-italic}}!";
var g2 = "<b>Yo</b>, <i>dude</i>!";

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ 
model: function() {
    return {greeting1: g1, greeting2: g2}
  }    
});

App.MyBoldComponent = Ember.Component.extend({tagName: "span"});

App.MyItalicComponent = Ember.Component.extend({tagName: "span"});
```

index.html

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
{{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/my-bold"><b>{{yield}}</b></script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/my-italic"><i>{{yield}}</i></script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
  <ol>
    <li>{{model.greeting1}}</li>
    <li>{{{model.greeting1}}}</li>
    <li>{{{model.greeting2}}}</li>
    <li>{{#my-bold}}Yo,{{/my-bold}} {{#my-italic}}dude!{{/my-italic}}</li>
  </ol> 
</script>
```

output:

1. {{#my-bold}}Yo{{/my-bold}}, {{#my-italic}}dude{{/my-italic}}!
2. {{#my-bold}}Yo{{/my-bold}}, {{#my-italic}}dude{{/my-italic}}!
3. **Yo**, *dude*!
4. **Yo**, *dude*!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Ember.js issue tracker https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11649 on dynamically inserting components:

> This isn't something we support, I also suspect we won't as it would require all of the htmlbars compiler client side and would likely be pretty slow. If you wish to add components dynamically. The component helper may be your best bet.

On that issue they are proposing to use the `{{component}}` helper, but that doesn't work with your code since you actually want to produce two component.

They are also talking about the RFC for contextual components: https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/64#issuecomment-111761176 which depending on their implementation would work similar to what you're doing. So what can you do?

As far as I can tell it's simply not possible to do with 1.13 (I tried quite a number of things) because rerender doesn't work, but they are going to fix it. If you downgrade to 1.12 you can do:

```
App.RenderTemplateComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  layout: function(){
    return Ember.Handlebars.compile(this.get('templateString'));
  }.property('templateString')
});
```

Then in your template something like:

```
{{render-template templateString="test {{x-foo}} {{x-foo}}"}}
```

Take a look at this JSFiddle:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jazayiyufi/1/edit?html,css,js,output